# Gets all switch cases

Tags: c#

I'm writing a console application with a switch that contains a lot of commands, and the command called "help" that could output all cases in the switch without have to write them all.

```
switch(Console.ReadLine())
{
case "help":
  Console.WriteLine("All switch cases");
break;

case "command1":
// Code
break;
}
```

Comment: There is no way to do this. You will either have to store them in a seperate array or not use a switch case

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I would encapsulate commands in seperate classes / objects and get rid of the switch statement. Have a look at the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). If you have encapsulate your commands, you can register them in a central repository. To generate help texts, you simply have to iterate all registered commands and let them generate the required help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would sugest using a dictionary, for example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
  { "help", doHelp },
  { "command1", doCommand1 }
};

// then you can do:
var action = dict["help"];
action();

// if you want to add another command later, use:
dict.Add("command2", () => doCommand2());
```

Comment: And if you've got some more time - encapsulate the whole command, not only the help texts..

Comment: Can't you use the new dictionary initializers?

Comment: Of course, I added this for you ;)

Comment: @thijmen321 Isn't it irrelevant which collection initialization style he uses?

Comment: @S.Spieker I think he means `["help"] = () => doHelp() ` - `C# 6` dictionary  initializers...

Comment: @ventiseis Ok, changed it :)